# Converting correctly bitmap from gallery to base64

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I develop an Android App and I develop a feature to take a picture from the gallery and to send it to my server and assign it to user as his profil picture.

I select an image (important : taken by ma camera) and I convert it to base64 before sending it to my server. When I get the image and I try to display it I have only part of the picture but not for image in png... I tried to change compressformat in JPEG and it's worst... I didn't understand the problem since 2 days I get crazy... Help Please :)

```
    private Bitmap bitmap; 



    public void chooseProfilePicture(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            InputStream stream = null;
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                try {
                    if (bitmap != null)
                        bitmap.recycle(); // recyle unused bitmaps
                    stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
// HERE THE IMAGE IS DISPLAYED 100% WELL

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (stream != null)
                        try {
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Log.e("EditProfilActivity", ex.getMessage());
                        }
                }
        }

public void save(View view) {

        if (bitmap != null) {

            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                bitmap.recycle();
                byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                picture = encodedImage;
// HERE WHEN I TRY TO DISPLAY THE IMAGE I HAVE ONLY A PART OF THE IMAGE
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage());
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show image form string(from encoding image file)?

```
byte[] imagebyteArry = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String imageString = encodeImage(imagebyteArry);
sendImageToserver(imageString);

............

String imageString = getImageFromserver();
byte[] imagebyteArry = decodeImage(imageString);
Search how to show image from byte[] in android?

public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);
}

public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
}
```

Comment: :) download jar file `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` jar